# capybara define optional parameter

Tags: capybara

```
 Given   Admin user with email and role:
```

and i wanna create same defintion with extra parametar

Given   Admin user with email and role and  drop table

try to write this fixture

```
Given(/^Admin user with email and role(?: and drop table (.*)):$/) do |table, drop|
  add_location :drop_tables => drop || false
  table.hashes.each_with_index do |value, key|
    value[:"Postal Code"] ||= nil
    add_admin_user :role_name => value[:"Role"], :admin_email => value[:"Email"]
  end
  clear_memcache
end
```

so if parametar doesn't exist, would be false by default, but if we have in definition drop table, should be drop_tables =>true

```
drop_tables => drop || false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is

```
Given(/^Admin user with email and role( and drop table)?:$/) do |drop,table|
  add_location :drop_tables => !!drop
  table.hashes.each_with_index do |value, key|
    value[:"Postal Code"] ||= nil
    add_admin_user :role_name => value[:"Role"], :admin_email => value[:"Email"]
  end
  clear_memcache
end
```

Which will set `drop_tables: true` if the " and drop table" text is used and 'drop_table: false' if it's not

Comment: tnx mate, you are great!